# 64 Bit Access Database Jet Engine

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, ms-access, cplex

I'm trying to run an optimization script within Visual Studio using C# and the CPLEX solver.

For data, I'm using Access 2013, though I'm utilizing the old .mdb file format.

I set up the database connection using the Access JET engine, which seems to require a 32-bit build.

```
public static string connectionString = "provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0; data source = " + filePath + dbName + ".mdb";
```

However, the version of CPLEX that I have is 64 bits (using the ILOG.Concert and ILOG.Cplex references), and will not run in a 32-bit build, else it throws a BadImageFormatException.

[image: BadImageFormatException]

Is there anything I can do besides trying to persuade my university's SysAdmins to install MSSQL Management Studio (which would take an act of congress)?

UPDATE: I do not have admin access on any computer that has a license for CPLEX, so I can't install the 64-bit drivers that Microsoft released with Office 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this Code for above Office 2007

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + pathnam + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! (though for Access I removed the Excel-specific part of the string)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 64bit version of the driver. Microsoft had to make it when they created the 64bit version of Office.

According to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/01/21/how-to-get-a-x64-version-of-jet.aspx

> Office 2010 will introduce a 64 bit version of Office.  With that is
>   coming a 64 bit version of the ACE Driver/Provider which will in
>   essence give you a 64 bit version of Jet.  The downside is that it
>   doesn’t ship with the operating system but will be a redistributable .

You can download that redistributable here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: I can't install that on a computer without admin access. And persuading my sysadmin (at a university with 20k+ students) to install it is a futile battle.